# What is the purpose of an arrow "->" in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I've been learning OCaml recently and as of now it would seem an arrow is used by the compiler to signify what the next type would be. For instance, `int -> int -> <fun>` an integer which returns an integer, which returns a function.

However, I was wondering if I can use it natively in OCaml code. In addition, if anyone would happen to know the appropriate name for it. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "use it natively"? Of course you can use it when you write down type signatures explicitly.

Comment: What you meant to copy-paste is something like: `let f a b = a + b;;
val f : int -> int -> int = <fun>`, in which `int -> int -> int` is the type of `f`. You can ignore the `= <fun>` part, which is meant to display the value of `f` informally.

Comment: For completeness it's important imho to comment on the use of arrows `->` in datatypes/type definitions as well e.g. `type 'a pp = Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit;;`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69683695/in-ocaml-a-variant-declaring-its-tags-with-a-colon and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69683695/in-ocaml-a-variant-declaring-its-tags-with-a-colon but for types (ADTs, GADTs) algebraic data types or generalized algebraic data types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The operator is usually called type arrow where `T1 -> T2` represents functions from type `T1` to type `T2`. For instance, the type of `+` is `int -> (int -> int)` because it takes two integers and returns another one.

The way `->` is defined, a function always takes one argument and returns only one element. A function with multiple parameters can be translated into a sequence of unary functions. We can interpret `1 + 2` as creating a +1 increment function (you can create it by evaluating `(+) 1` in the OCaml command line) to the number 2. This technique is called Currying or Partial Evaluation.

Let's have a look at OCaml's output when evaluating a term :

```
# 1 + 2;;
- : int = 3

# (+) 1 ;;
- : int -> int = <fun>
```

The term`1+2` is of type integer and has a value of `3` and the term `(+) 1` is a function from integers to integers. But since the latter is a function, OCaml cannot print a single value. As a placeholder, it just prints `<fun>`, but the type is left of the `=`.

You can define your own functions with the fun keyword:

```
# (fun x -> x ^ "abc");;
- : bytes -> bytes = <fun>
```

This is the function which appends "abc" to a given string x. Let's take the syntax apart: `fun x -> term` means that we define a function with argument `x` and this `x` can now appear within `term`. Sometimes we would like to give function names, then we use the `let` construction:

```
# let append_abc = (fun x -> x ^ "abc") ;;
val append_abc : bytes -> bytes = <fun>
```

Because the `let f = fun x -> ...` is a bit cumbersome, you can also write:

```
let append_abc x = x ^ "abc" ;;
val append_abc : bytes -> bytes = <fun>
```

In any case, you can use your new function as follows:

```
# append_abc "now comes:" ;;
- : bytes = "now comes:abc"
```

The variable `x` is replaced by `"now comes:"` and we obtain the expression:

```
"now comes:" ^ "abc"
```

which evaluates to `"now comes:abc"`.

@Charlie Parker asked about the arrow in type declarations. The statement

```
type 'a pp = Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit
```

introduces a synonym `pp` for the type `Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit`. The rule for the arrow there is the same as above: a function of type `'a pp` takes a `formatter`, a value of arbitrary type `'a` and returns `()` (the only value of `unit` type)

For example, the following function is of type Format.formatter -> int -> unit (the %d enforces the type variable `'a` to become `int`):

```
utop # let pp_int fmt x = Format.fprintf fmt "abc %d" x;;
val pp_int : formatter -> int -> unit = <fun>
```

Unfortunately the toplevel does not infer `int pp` as a type so we don't immediately notice(*). We can still introduce a new variable with a type annotation that we can see what's going on:

```
utop # let x : int pp = pp_int ;;
val x : int pp = <fun>
utop # let y : string pp = pp_int ;;
Error: This expression has type formatter -> int -> unit
       but an expression was expected of type
         string pp = formatter -> string -> unit
       Type int is not compatible with type string
```

The first declaration is fine because the type annotation agrees with the type inferred by OCaml. The second one is in conflict with the inferred type (`'a'` can not be both `int` and `string` at the same time).

Just a remark: type can also be used with records and algebraic data types to create new types (instead of synonyms). But the type arrow keeps its meaning as a function.

(*) Imagine having multiple synonymes, which one should the toplevel show? Therefore synonyms are usually expanded.

Comment: I am seeing the arrows used in an actual type definition e.g. `open Format;;
type 'a pp = Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit;;`. In this context what does the arrow mean? I am usually used seeing data types defined using constructors. Without this I feel confused. Can you comment (or expand your answer) to mention how arrows are used in type definitions? thanks!

Comment: I added some comment regarding type declaration - in principle, the meaning is again the type arrow. It's just not that easy to notice the type synonym in the toplevel.

Comment: what if it's in a type definition?

Comment: If it's a type, the `->` is always a type arrow - the polymorphism is independent of the concept. But your answer about GADTs indeed fills a hole I left out - it allows for type annotations in pattern matching where the type occurs at an unexpected location. But again, the meaning of the type arrow as function type is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

The given answer doesn't work for ADTs, GADTs, for that see: [In OCaml, a variant declaring its tags with a colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69683695/in-ocaml-a-variant-declaring-its-tags-with-a-colon)

e.g.

```
type 'l generic_argument =
| GenArg : ('a, 'l) abstract_argument_type * 'a -> 'l generic_argument
```