# In OCaml, a variant declaring its tags with a colon

Tags: types, ocaml, variant

Looking at the following code:

```ml
type z = Z of z

type 'a s = Z | S of 'a

type _ t = Z : z t | S : 'n t -> 'n s t
```

the last line contains a generic variant, or what seems like one, but instead of using the keyword `of` it uses the colon symbol `:`. Why is that? And how am I supposed to read this type?

Looking at the OCaml grammar for type declarations: https://ocaml.org/manual/types.html it doesn't seem obvious if this is really a variant, and it even looks like this is a mix of a label and a variant.

Comment: The definition of `t` is a GADT. The documentation is here: https://ocaml.org/releases/4.13/htmlman/gadts.html. In essence `t` represents a Peano model of the integers (it seems to me). So maybe `z` isn't such a useless type after all.

Comment: oh I see, that's the GADT syntax. BTW isn't the constructor `Z` in the type `z` shadowed by the type `s` similarly named tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating GADT expression in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429552/creating-gadt-expression-in-ocaml)

Comment: likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72985372/what-does-a-square-bracket-or-mean-in-a-generalized-algebraic-data-typ

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72971810/what-does-it-mean-to-have-colons-and-arrows-in-user-defined-type-defini?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a definition of the [generalized algebraic data type](https://ocaml.org/manual/gadts-tutorial.html#sec63) (GADT). This language feature was introduced in the 4.0 release of OCaml and the syntax of the regular algebraic data types (ADT) was extended with this column variant to enable constructor-specific constraints.

The regular ADT syntax `<Constr> [of <args>]` is used to introduce a constructor `<Constr>` that has the specified arguments, e.g.,

```
type student = Student of string * int
```

The generalized syntax, `<Constr> : [<args>] -> <constr>` uses `:` instead of `of` but adds an extra place for specifying the type constraint, e.g.,

```
type student = Student : string * int -> student
```

The constraint has to be an instance of the defined type. And it is useful when either the defined type or the constructor arguments (or both) are polymorphic, i.e., reference type variables. A better example is a type-safe abstract syntax tree of an expression language, e.g.,

```
type _ exp = 
  | Int : int -> int exp
  | Str : string -> string exp
  | Cat : string exp * string exp -> string exp
  | Add : int exp * int exp -> int exp
```

Using this representation we can write a statically typed interpreter where we will not have to deal with cases `Add (Str "foo", Int 42)` as it is impossible to construct such values because of the constraints on the `Cat` constructor, which requires that both arguments have the `string` type.

Another use case of GADT is to enable existential types that could be used to implement dynamic typing and ad-hoc polymorphism ala Haskell type classes. In an existential constructor, some type variables that occur in the constructor argument types are not present in the constraint type, e.g.,

```
type show = Show : {data : 'a; show : 'a -> string} -> show
let show (Show {show; data}) = show data
```

So that now we can have a heterogeneous containers,

```
let entries = [
    Show {data=42; show=string_of_int};
    Show {data="foo"; show=fun x -> x};
]
```

Which we can show,

```
# List.map show entries;;
- : string list = ["42"; "foo"]
```

Comment: Can I understand the "constraint" as kind of like the "return type" of the constructor?  That's how it looks in these examples e.g. `Add : int exp * int exp -> int exp` means that `Add (Int 1, Int 1)` should return ... `Int 2` I guess?

Comment: Sort of, it is the type that is ascribed to this constructor. It could be an arbitrary type, e.g., you can freely define something like `Add : int exp * int exp -> string exp` if you like, so it is not necessary that the constraint type has any relevance to the construction of the variant.

Comment: thanks for explaining!  I sort of get it, need to have a play around for myself...