# What does it mean to have colons “:” and arrows “->” in user defined type definitions in OCaml?

Tags: types, ocaml, abstract-data-type

[I am seeing](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.11/api/coq/Genarg/index.html#type-generic_argument):

```
type 'l generic_argument =
| GenArg : ('a, 'l) abstract_argument_type * 'a -> 'l generic_argument
```

but I don't understand what that means.

I know what the typical `of t1 * t2 .... * tn` syntax means e.g.

```
type 'a list =
  | Nil
  | Cons of 'a * ('a list);;
```

but don't know what the colon `:` and `->` mean in type definitions. What does it mean?

Btw, I've seen `->` them in pattern matching.

---

cross: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/what-does-it-mean-to-have-colons-and-arrows-in-user-defined-type-definitions/10166

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72985372/what-does-a-square-bracket-or-mean-in-a-generalized-algebraic-data-typ

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69683695/in-ocaml-a-variant-declaring-its-tags-with-a-colon?noredirect=1&lq=1