# What does square brackets `[` and `]` mean in a data type definition in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, algebraic-data-types

I saw [the following](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.11/api/coq/Genarg/index.html#type-rlevel):

```
type rlevel = [
| `rlevel
]
```

but I've never seen this before and the tutorials for ADTs (algebraic data types) are not super helpful nor is the OCaml grammar.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

The type `rlevel` is a type abbreviation for a polymorphic variant type (https://ocaml.org/manual/polyvariant.html) which contains only one constructor `` `rlevel `` .

Comment: ok so I can name a constructor with `'rlevel`? What would be an example value?

Comment: Rather \`rlevel is polymorphic variant constructor and polymorphic variants are structural. Thus \`rlevel is a value and the only inhabitant of type ``[ `rlevel ]``